# Access VBA Excel: Formatting Excel and Range Application/Object error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've been searching for a while on a solution, and what I'm finding is that sometimes the solution works but then most of the time the code stops working or causes an error. Very frustrating...

Here's a snippet of the code and the line that's failing is where I am attempting to select a range using the xldown and xlright functions, but I just can't seem to get the syntax right or I'm running into the object error.  Please help - I will provide more code, if necessary.

```
        With ws
'            LastRow = .Range("S" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lRow = .Range("S" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'            .Range("S2:" & .Range("Z" & LastRow)).Select
        Set rng = .Range("S2", Range("S2").End(xlToRight)).Select
```

As you can see I've tried several things - some options I've already deleted. I've tried inside the with statement and outside the with statement. Still failing.  Thanks!

Comment: `Range("S2").End(xlToRight)` is missing the dereference operator (`.`) in front of it. It's not tied to the `Worksheet` in your `With` block.

Comment: Ack - the power of a period!  Let me see if that does it.  I meant to include last time that I was also getting a rng = nothing message although I already declared it correctly at the top of the code. Let me see if that's still the case.

Comment: That's still happening after the change - saying Object Required. Not sure why though. Here's what I have above the code:    Dim rng As Range 
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strReportFileDetails, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Vendor Items in Wave")

Comment: Sorry to keep adding comments... ok - the code is selecting the range across but then breaking. So that last line is working but breaking at the same time.  And then I still need it to continue selecting down to the last row.  I'll try to work with this more, but please let me know a better solution if there is one. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies again, because I'm not making myself clear.  This is what I'm trying to accomplish:  
    Set rng = ws.Range("S2:Z3")
Except that I want it dynamic depending on the worksheet rows.  This time it worked hard-coded, but this runs on a loop and may fail the next go-round.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ws.Range("S2").CurrentRegion.Select
```

This will work, if the range you want to select is contiguous.

(Can you post a mock-up of what your sheet might look like, instead of trying to describe it?)

Comment: Right, I forgot about Current Region! I'll give that a shot and then past the mockup when I get back at my computer. Thank you.

Comment: Hello again - CurrentRegion does not work because it selects all cells that as you said were contiguous. I was thinking continguous only from the starting place.  I won't post a screenshot, but I'm only trying to select cell S2 (this can be static) through the last row.  The column can also be static, which is "Z", but I figured I didn't need that.  I've tried this before, but the "selection" parts cause errors. I've removed all of the "selection" references in this code to alleviate those errors.  Are there other options?
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've worked it out.  Per the previous message, I was using this line below to select the desired range, which would have worked but I was getting errors from using "selection":
    `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`
However, what I needed to do was explicitly reference the starting range, and now it is working fine. The code below is selecting from the starting point "S2" to the end cell.
    `Set rng = .Range(ws.Range("S2"), ws.Range("S2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))`
Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: Personally, I don't like to use .End(xlDown), etc. because it is too "mechanical" (duplicating what I would do with the keyboard). I prefer to use the Excel object model to identify the range I need, then act on it. In almost (probably every) case, it is possible to do this. Anyway, seems like you are getting the results you want/need, Great!